# Deferencing pointer to incomplete type error in C

Tags: c

I'd like to know why I am getting this,

Error:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   strncpy(variables->part1[i], environ[i], placement);
```

main Code:

```
struct vars {
  char **part1;
  char **part2;
} ;

static struct vars *variables;

exportenviron(&variables);
```

function Code:

```
void exportenviron(struct vars* variables)
{
    int i;
    char *pch;

    int placement;

    for(i=0; environ[i]; i++) {
        pch = strchr(environ[i], '=');
        placement = pch-environ[i]+1;
        strncpy(variables->part1[i], environ[i], placement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done malloc for `variables`? Calling of should be `exportenviron(variables)` ...

Comment: Try `exportenviron(variables);` instead of `exportenviron(&variables);`

Comment: @Ani. Okay let's say I malloc. `variables = (struct vars *) malloc(sizeof(struct vars));` I get the same error.

Comment: Moving the `struct vars` into my header file did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file containing `exportenviron` isn't seeing the actual definition of your struct: instead, it only knows that `struct vars` exists, but not what's in it. For example, perhaps you have a header file `vars.h` included by the .c file with `exportenviron` in it, and `vars.h` contains only `struct vars;`

Comment: Furthermore, for the call `exportenviron(&variables)` must be assuming an implicit declaration of the `exportenviron` function. Both the definition of the type `struct vars` and the declaration (not definition) of `exportenviron` should be in a header file, visible both to the file containing the call and to the file containing the function definition. And a higher compiler warning level should cause it to warn you about the call with no visible declaration (which is legal in C90, illegal in C99, and to be avoided in any version of the language).

Comment: I don't think it "must be", @KeithThompson. It's entirely possible `exportenviron` is in a header somewhere, isn't it? What about this behavior tells you that the function is implicitly declared?

Comment: It's defined to expect an argument of type `struct vars*`, but it's called with an argument of type `struct vars**`. If a correct prototype were visible, the call would have been rejected.

Comment: @amalloy. I kind of stumbled on this myself but I'll accept this answer because it does answer the question.